# Is it possible to customise tf.estimator for Unsupervised Learning with self-defined evaluation graph not having loss?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am implementing a item2vec model using the idea of word2vec 
 with tf.estimator API for product recommendation.

There's no problem implementing training part with tf.estimator. The process is same as word2vec, and I see each transactions as a sentence. Only difference is how to generate training input:`(target_item, context_item)` pairs. After training the pseudo-classification problem, I could use trained embedding vector for each items to measure relationship between them.

The problem is, for evaluation part, it is not a typical supervised learning evaluation, ie. with eval data as input, going through the same graph, we obtain predictions and accuracy.

The evaluation input data I would like to use, is in a totally different format from training input data. 
Format of Eval input data: `(target_item, {context_item1, context_item2, ...})`. With this, I could obtain top_k nearest items for each context_items and then see if the target_item is in the collection of these nearest items, so that I could obtain a hit-ratio from it.

However, `tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec()` for `mode = MODE.EVAL` requires a `loss` as input. So, does it mean evaluation can only reuse part of the training graph? What could I do if I don't have a loss function for evaluation in my case, as the evaluation does not go through the classification anymore?

Many thanks.